# read the url content

Tags: java

I want to read the url content by bytes. I have to read the 64 kb from the content of url.

```
public void readUrlBytes(String address) {
    StringBuilder builder = null;
    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int i = 0;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        input = new BufferedInputStream(urlc.getInputStream());
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            builder.append(bytesRead);
            if (i==64) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    } catch (IOException l_exception) {
        //handle or throw this
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch(IOException igored) {}
        }
    }

}
```

The above coding is for read character wise.

I need to read bytes.

Comment: What are you asking?  The method `java.io.InputStream.read()` is reading a `byte` from the stream.

Comment: Ok, after looking over the new code you pasted in, there are a few other problems.

You never instantiate the StrinngBuilder, you will get a NullPointerException when you first try to use it.  Secondly, you can't call append(byte[]) and expect anything useful to happen.   You say you want to read in bytes, but it appears you are trying to get a String after everything is said and done.  Is this binary or character data you are trying to read in?

Answer (score 1):

Like Bozho said, you already are reading in bytes.  However, it's probably more efficient to read everything into a byte array rather than doing it one byte at a time.

```
BufferedInputStream input = null;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
  try {
     URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
     input=  new BufferedInputStream( urlc.getInputStream() );
     int bytesRead;
     while( ( bytesRead = input.read(buffer) ) != -1 )
     {
       //do something with the bytes, array has data 0 to bytesRead (exclusive)
     }
  }
  catch( IOException l_exception ) {
       //handle or throw this
  }
  finally {
     if (input != null) {
        try {
          input.close();
        }
        catch(IOException igored) {}
     }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for replay, ya, i know this, 
but i want to read only 64kb from the content.
is there any possible?

Comment: I can take a wild guess why you are getting an error (sunspot activity), but if you let us know what the exact error you are getting it'd be easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the cast to `char`, you have a byte.

If you're going to store the whole content into memory, you can use `ByteArrayOutputStream` and write each byte to it. Finally call `toByteArray()` to obtain the array of bytes:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1) {
    baos.write(byteRead);
}

byte[] result = baos.toByteArray();
```

**Update:**  you mentioned you want only 64 kb. To achieve that just check whether `baos.size()` has reached 64*1024 and `break`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read directly from the InputStream object returned:

```
  InputStream istream = urlc.getInputStream(); 

  int byteRead; 
  while ((byteRead = istream.read()) != -1) 
    builder.append(byteRead); 

  istream.close();
```

Comment: I'd assume the builder is a StringBuilder, so writing an int to it would just append it to a string sequence of numbers.

Comment: i just update my question program.

but i am getting error when run the program.

Comment: @Bozho - good point, but the question I was answering was how to read bytes, not chars - however, I fluffed anyway as InputStream and BufferedInputStream both read bytes. I think I know now what the OP wanted - see separate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it,

```
                    input = urlc.getInputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int n = - 1;

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4096);

                    while ( (n = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                            if (n > 0)
                            {
                                    baos.write(buffer, 0, n);
                            }
                    }
                    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a separate answer as I suddenly realised another way the question could be interpreted: I think the OP wants to convert a stream of bytes representing the internal format of characters in a specific character set into the corresponding characters. For example, converting ASCII codes into ASCII characters.

This isn't a complete answer, but hopefully will put the OP on the right track if I've understood correctly. I'm using utf-8 as an example here:

```
BufferedInputStream istream = new BufferedInputStream(urlc.getInputStream() ); 
int numBytesAvailable = istream.available(); 
byte[] buffer = new byte[numBytesAvailable]; 
istream.read(buffer); 

ByteBuffer tempBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer); 
Charset utf8Chars = Charset.forName("UTF-8"); 
CharBuffer chars = utf8Chars.decode(tempBuffer);
```

Now you have a buffer of chars as Java sees them (you can use chars.array() to get a char[] out of it), so they can be printed as a string.

WARNING: You will need to get the entire stream into a byte buffer before trying to decode; decoding a buffer when you don't know the correct end of the character's internal byte sequence will result in corrupt characters!

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the *first* 64KB from an URL into a `byte[]`?

That's easy:

```
public byte[] getFirst64KbFromUrl(String address) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = null;
    byte[] first64kb = new byte[64 * 1024];
    try {
        input = new URL(address).openStream();
        input.read(first64kb);
    } finally {
        if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch(IOException ignore) {}
    }
    return first64kb;
}
```

If you *actually* have a problem with converting those bytes to `String`, here's how you could do it:

```
String string = new String(first64kb);
```

This however takes the platform default encoding into account. You'd like to use the server-side specified encoding for this which is available in the [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) response header.

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(address).openConnection();
// ...
String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
String charset = "UTF-8"; // Let's default it to UTF-8.
for (String param : contentType.replace(" ", "").split(";")) {
    if (param.startsWith("charset=")) {
        charset = param.split("=", 2)[1];
        break;
    }
}
// ...
String string = new String(first64kb, charset);
```

**See also**:

- [Java basic IO tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/)
- [How to use `java.net.URLConnection`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153)